# Sorting list of numbers with prefix in python

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to come up with a specific order key in Python to sort my list of string numbers with specific criteria.
The list elements all look like this:

```
["5,4287", "2,86", "4,92", "6,12", "6,11"]
```

and so on.

I want the elements of this list to be ordered in a specific order of criteria:

- First order them by the prefix (the number before ',')
- Then order them by the suffix

The resulting list should look like this:

```
["2,86", "4,92", "5,4287", "6,11", "6,12"]
```

I don't know how I can sort by multiple criteria in python or if this is even possible.

Comment: you can convert them float and than sort them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `str.split` on comma and convert to `int`

**Ex:**

```
data =  ["5,4287", "2,86", "4,92", "6,12", "6,11"]
data.sort(key=lambda x: tuple(map(int, x.split(","))))
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
['2,86', '4,92', '5,4287', '6,11', '6,12']
```